# Three columns in line

Tags: html, css

```
#maindiv
{
display:table;
text-align:center;
border:2px solid #94a2af;
width:100%;
}

#leftsidebar
{
display:table-cell;
width: 26%;
background-color: #af9495;
border:1px solid #94a2af;
}

#rightsidebar
{
display:table-cell;
width: 24%;
background-color: #94a2af;
border:1px solid #94a2af;
}

#center
{
text-align:center;
display:table-cell;
background-color: #f2ebca;
width:50%;
}
```

I am trying to line up three columns in a row that will be equal height, I found this table solution to get the height(and it worked great) but I can not get the table-cells to display in the correct order. The center one displays on the right and I can't seem to find a solution.

Go easy I'm brand new to this :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  If you include an [mcve] it is easier, faster to provide you the help you seek - can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your current result, and your desired result?

Comment: This works [perfectly](https://jsfiddle.net/0tqo7fn7/1/) fine?

Comment: Thanks everyone, Vincent's solution made me realize I had my html mixed up a little. Works perfect now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML to go with that CSS should look something like this:

```
<div id="maindiv">
    <div id="leftsidebar">Col 1</div>
    <div id="center">Col 2</div>
    <div id="rightsidebar">Col 3</div>
</div>
```

Please post your HTML for a more specific response.